# Historical component changes of EURO STOXX 50 index

Tags: market-data, historical-data, event-study, ticker-mapping, index-data

I would like to download the historical component changes of EURO STOXX 50 index to conduct an academic research. That is, I would like to know the historical changes to the composition of these indices (change of constituents).

I tried to search the official Europe indices website: https://www.stoxx.com/end-of-the-day-data
but the button to download the data is disabled, as you can see from the following screenshot:

[image]

How can I get what I need?

UPDATE: I have learned that the Bloomberg CHNG command will provide me all changes to the index constituents for a selected date, but it is not available for the EURO STOXX 50. Through Bloomberg I can get the composition of the EURO STOXX 50 for a desired date. In this way, comparing the different compositions of the index on different dates, I could get the list of additions / removals from the index, but it would take a long time as I would have compare the composition of the index for about 20 years... Any idea? Is it possible that there is no way to obtain these (simple) data, not even for a fee?

Comment: You might try to 1) reach out to them directly, or 2) try your luck with the Bloomberg or Reuters terminal of your institution.

Comment: Can you confirm me that Bloomberg or Reuters allows me to get what I need?

Comment: For Bloomberg, the answer may be different for different subscribers (some data items may be optional, at extra cost). So you have to check if this is one of the capabilities your university has subscribed to.

Comment: I have learned that the Bloomberg CHNG command will provide me all changes to the index constituents for a selected date, but it is not available for the EURO STOXX 50. Through Bloomberg I can get the composition of the EURO STOXX 50 for a desired date. In this way, comparing the different compositions of the index on different dates, I could get the list of additions / removals from the index, but it would take a long time as I would have compare the composition of the index for about 20 years... Any idea?
Is it possible that there is no way to obtain these (simple) data, not even for a fee?